# Using JavaCC to read input from a text file

Tags: java, io, javacc

I am trying to make JavaCC use the input from a text file called input.txt. However, I cannot figure out how to do so. I try to setup an InputStream and pass that to a StringReader, but I don't think StringReader takes this type of parameter. My relevant code is below:

```
InputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\input.txt");
java.io.StringReader sr = new java.io.StringReader(fis);
SimpleCharStream scs = new SimpleCharStream(sr);
LexicalStatesSpacesTokenManager mgr = new LexicalStatesSpacesTokenManager(scs);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `StringReader` gets its input from a string. You want to get input from a file so use a `FileReader`.

See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) for the details.